# js scripts not loading in jinja2 template

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I have a situation where, replacing a url string `"/CreditHistory/10216"` with a jinja2 variable `{{creditNumbers|safe}}`, messes up the loading of javascript files. More specifically, this works;

```
{% block Scripter %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/assets/js/crossfilter/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/assets/js/d3/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/assets/js/dc.js/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/assets/js/queue/queue.js"></script>
<script src='./static/assets/js/graphsFordringer.js' type='text/javascript' charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

queue().defer(d3.json, "/CreditHistory/10216").await(makeGraphs);

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

But, this does not;

```
{% block Scripter %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/assets/js/crossfilter/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/assets/js/d3/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/assets/js/dc.js/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/assets/js/queue/queue.js"></script>
<script src='./static/assets/js/graphsFordringer.js' type='text/javascript' charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

queue().defer(d3.json, "{{creditNumbers|safe}}").await(makeGraphs);

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

The errors that gets thrown in the web-browser implies that none of the javascript files get loaded. One of them is for example that queue is not a defined function. 
What is also apparent is that the `"{{creditNumbers|safe}}"` variable does load to `"/CreditHistory/10216"`. So, in short the variable loading seems to break the javascript loading. Not that I have found reference to similar issues in the documentation, so that probably is not what is happening.

EDIT:

It now seems that I have misunderstood the entire situation. It looks like it is the way that the jinja2 template variable is declared in the `app.py` file that is the root cause.

The `@app.route`code that is failing is;

```
@app.route('/KundeFordringer/<int:KundeNr>')
def fordringer(KundeNr):

    jsonSti = "/CreditHistory/"+str(KundeNr)
    return render_template("fordringer.html", creditNumbers=jsonSti)
```

However, if I change the code to the following, it works fine;

```
@app.route('/KundeFordringer')
def fordringer():

    return render_template("fordringer.html", creditNumbers="/CreditHistory/10216")
```

As mentioned previously, viewing the source code from the web browser, one could see that the `"/CreditHistory/10216"`was loaded when using the first `@app.route` declaration. But apparently something is, never the less, off with that way of doing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @doru, thank you for the suggestion, but it now seems that I misunderstood the problem, and that the problem is stemming from the `app.py` declarations, see EDIT in question.

Comment: What do you see when inspecting your `<script>` from the chrome dev tools ?

Comment: @TimothéeJeannin The console throws 16 errors. 14 of which are "Failed to load resource" errors of either css of js files. the last 2 errors are uncaught reference errors, related to two functions, that should have been declared in the js files that did not load.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the resource you're trying to load is available ? Can you check if the generated url is correct ? Try copy pasting the exact url of the resources that failed to load and copy that in your browser omnibox.

Comment: @TimothéeJeannin I do not know whether or not I should cry or laugh, because that was the problem. The js file paths started with `./` instead of just `/`. I would definitely like to thank you by checking an answer as accepted. You cannot believe how much time I have used with this problem...

Comment: @Rookie Good to know it resolved your issue. Good luck with your project! :)

Comment: @TimothéeJeannin thanks buddy! I think I will definitely need some luck along the way! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading of the javascript files is relative to the current url. 
Basically if you are browsing

```
http://mywebsite.com/KundeFordringer/456
```

Then the browser is going to try to load those files:

```
http://mywebsite.com/KundeFordringer/456/static/assets/js/crossfilter/crossfilter.js
http://mywebsite.com/KundeFordringer/456/static/assets/js/d3/d3.js
http://mywebsite.com/KundeFordringer/456/static/assets/js/dc.js/dc.js
http://mywebsite.com/KundeFordringer/456/static/assets/js/queue/queue.js
```

What you want is probably

```
http://mywebsite.com/static/assets/js/crossfilter/crossfilter.js
http://mywebsite.com/static/assets/js/d3/d3.js
http://mywebsite.com/static/assets/js/dc.js/dc.js
http://mywebsite.com/static/assets/js/queue/queue.js
```

Their might be a problem either with your script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/assets/js/dc.js/dc.js"></script>
```

That needs to be renamed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/dc.js/dc.js"></script>
```

Or a problem with your `static_url_path`.